# Data not save to the database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I want to save form data to database. I get a success message in the url. But the data get not saved to the database. `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` seems to get not executed. Can anyone explain me the below code error?

```php
if (isset($_POST['register-submit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $type = $_POST['utype'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`idroles`, `user_email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`) VALUES((SELECT `idroles` FROM `roles` WHERE `name`= $type), ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location../View/login_register.php");
        exit();
    } else if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        $hashpwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $hashpwd);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header("Location:../View/login_register.php?success");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments

Comment: And don’t do `if( !foo() ) {…} else if( foo() ) {…}`, you are needlessly calling the same function twice here.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/2408342) and post the sql errors in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `mysqli_stmt_execute` succeded by doing so:

```php
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    header("Location:../View/login_register.php?success");
    exit();
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    exit();
}
```